# copy doesn't support the nested "if" element in Ant-contrib Nested Loop

Tags: ant, copy, ant-contrib

I need to copy all dml.sql files to inside DB2_List.txt file if DML.sql file is present. But after executing this file i'm getting error like this:
copy doesn't support the nested "if" element.

Please let me know if you have any better idea about the nested loop in Ant.

```
<available file="DB/DML.sql" property="db.check.present"/>
<copy file="DB/DDL.sql" tofile="DB2/DB2_List.txt" >
<if> 
 <equals arg1="${db.check.present}" arg2="true"/>
 <then> 
 <filterchain> 
    <concatfilter append="DB/DML.sql" /> 
    <tokenfilter delimoutput="${line.separator}" /> 
</filterchain> 
</then> 
</if> 
</copy>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to accomplish what you are after, you just have to approach it quite differently in Ant.  Just note that you will need to utilize separate targets.

```
<target name="db.check">
  <available file="DB/DML.sql" property="db.check.present"/>
</target>
<target name="db.copy" depends="db.check" if="db.check.present">
  <copy file="DB/DDL.sql" tofile="DB2/DB2_List.txt" >
    <filterchain> 
      <concatfilter append="DB/DML.sql" /> 
      <tokenfilter delimoutput="${line.separator}" /> 
    </filterchain> 
  </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Ant 1.9.1 which supports special [if/unless](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) attributes on tags. This ***might*** be possible:

```
 <project name="mysterious.moe" basedir="."  default="package"
    xmlns:if="ant:if"
    xmlns:unless="ant:unless"/>

    <target name="db.copy">
        <available file="DB/DML.sql" property="db.check.present"/>
        <copy file="DB/DDL.sql" 
            tofile="DB2/DB2_List.txt">
            <filterchain if:true="db.ceck.present"> 
                <concatfilter append="DB/DML.sql" /> 
                <tokenfilter delimoutput="${line.separator}" /> 
            </filterchain> 
       </copy>
    <target>
...
</project>
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use two separate copies. You can't put `<if>` antcontrib inside tasks. Only around tasks:

```
<available file="DB/DML.sql" property="db.check.present"/>
<if> 
    <equals arg1="${db.check.present}" arg2="true"/>
    <then> 
        <copy file="DB/DDL.sql" tofile="DB2/DB2_List.txt" >
            <filterchain> 
                <concatfilter append="DB/DML.sql" /> 
                <tokenfilter delimoutput="${line.separator}" /> 
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
        </then>
        <else>
            <copy file="DB/DDL.sql" tofile="DB2/DB2_List.txt" >
        </else>
    </if> 
</copy>
```

Comment: Hi David, If there are four db files and i need to check the availability of all four files and based on the availability i need to copy contents from the available files into a single text file. For example: If four db files like dbddl, dbdml, normalddl and normaldml, then i  need to check for following scenarios. In first case, if there all four files available(present), then copy contents from all four files and paste into one text file. In second case if there are only three files, then copy contents from all three files and paste into a text file. and so on.

Comment: Take a look at the [`<macrodef/>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) task. You can create a `<copydb>` macro task that will verify, and if needed, copy the db file to your text file.